# How do I print non English text from its unicode in Android

Tags: java, android

I need to display non English text in it's own language. Ex:  Japanese name in Japanese

This is the code,

```
   String.format(Locale.JAPANESE,"%s %s","%E9%A6%96%E7%9B%B8","%E9%A6%96%E7%9B%B8");
```

The out put for this is : `%E9%A6%96%E7%9B%B8`

The converting not work. But if I print Japanese text(not the unicode), it is displaying on Android screen so not a font issue. 
I read similar questions and answers here and non of them work for me. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

For unicode, you can try, say you have a TextView:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(your_unicode_here));
```

If you need to translate it, I suggest you use a translation API or a hard-coded mapped solution w/ Japanese, English strings etc.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I tried this earlier but not work.

Comment: Make sure the unicode that you have is in unicode format, I tried decoding the current unicode you have, I think it's not valid

Comment: hmm, I'm getting it from the server. I will check it. Honestly I don't have much idea about this it's kind of old project and adding new features.

Comment: You can try encoding, decoding here: https://www.online-toolz.com/tools/text-unicode-entities-convertor.php also it usually begins with %u